# Word Processing Document open Word(docx) get "The specified package is invalid. The main part is missing" error

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk

Get "The specified package is invalid. The main part is missing" from WordProcessingDocument.Open()

I have two files: One is original file and another is Save As version from the original file.

Original get error at WordprocessingDocument.Open. Save As version is able to process normally.

I compared two files xml but nothing suspicious found.

The path and fileName is valid but it will hit error.

```
using (var wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path + "/" + fileName, true))
```

“The specified package is invalid. The main part is missing.”

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve], and the problematic file.

Comment: Sorry. Cant share the files due to p&c stuffs

Comment: Cant help without that.

Comment: What is the origin of the original file? Does Word display any warnings when you try to open it?

Comment: A template from my client. Client add stuffs on top of that template. No warning when I open the file with Word

Answer (score 0):

It is because the package you're trying to open is invalid. Please make sure the package has the part of "maindocument.xml".

This error may occur at this situation: the package tried to open is created by the windows context menu, then its size is 0 until you open the file and save it even without any changes in Word 2007. After open-and-save, the file should be opened correctly by the SDK